# Show error of two strings are equal in unit testing

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I have created a small Laravel project and I am applying unit testing on my project. When I fill wrong credentials in function, it doesn't redirect to the login page and shows error on terminal saying Failed asserting that two strings are equal. Here is my code...

```
$credentials = [
    'email' => 'test@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'wrongcode'
];

$this->post('/login', $credentials)->assertRedirect('/login');
```

But when i change `assertRedirect('/login')` to `assertRedirect('/')` , it works fine

```
$credentials = [
    'email' => 'test1234@gmail.com',
    'password' => '98756412'
];

$this->post('/login', $credentials)->assertRedirect('/');
```

Answer (score 1):

assertRedirect checks two string, one of them is an argument of method, 2nd is redirect path. Looks like everything works fine. You write a test, test failed, you have feedback to improve application. In that case, the redirect path is different than expected by you.

Answer (score 0):

There should be 2 different methods for an individual scenario like below.

```
public function testCorrectCredential() {

  $credentials = [
    'email' => 'test1234@gmail.com',
    'password' => '98756412'
  ];

   $this->post('/login', $credentials)->assertRedirect('/');
}

public function testInCorrectCredential() {

      $credentials = [
        'email' => 'incorrect@gmail.com',
        'password' => '98756412'
      ];

       $this->post('/login', $credentials)->assertRedirect('/incorrect-url');
    }
```